# Only two digit year input in MUI (v5) Datepicker

Tags: javascript, material-ui, date-fns

I'm using the MUI (v5) Datepicker for user birthday input. I've localized it to german language. So the input is `DD.MM.YYYY`.

Now many german users are using a short year value like `DD.MM.YY`. But this input would result in wrong values:

Input `05.01.20` gives me `Sun Jan 05 0020 00:00:00 GMT+0053`. This leads me to two problems:

1. How can I 'force' the user to input four digit year values? Typing two digits results in a valid (but useless) date.
2. Or (and this would be better) how can I check and handle two digit year values? I would think future values (`80`) should get used as `1980` and `18` should result in `2018`.

For me, the second point would be the better solution, so I would have to set the input generally to the format `DD.MM.YY` and handle those inputs as described. But how do I change the input format of the DatePicker?

```
import React from 'react'
import AdapterDateFns from '@mui/lab/AdapterDateFns'
import LocalizationProvider from '@mui/lab/LocalizationProvider'
import DatePicker from '@mui/lab/DatePicker'
import deLocale from 'date-fns/locale/de'
import { toDate, isValid } from 'date-fns'

const Component = () => {
    const [birthday, setBirthday] = React.useState<Date>(null)
    const handleDateChange = (value: any) => {
        console.log(isValid(value))
        setBirthday(toDate(value))
    }
    
    return (
        <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns} locale={deLocale}>
            <DatePicker
                disableFuture
                mask="__.__.____"
                value={birthday}
                onChange={handleDateChange}
                renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField {...params} />
                )}
            />
        </LocalizationProvider>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always a question of balance for these kind of problems. What would be the more efficient and practical for **both** the end-user and the developer?

Being french, I understand the two-digits years thing, but it's not worth the hassle in my opinion.

Yes, the end-user would have to input 4 digits instead of 2 (that's like, 0.5s of his time anyway), but then you don't have to spend 2 or 3 hours (or more) to try and handle all the specific cases, and take the risk to save invalid dates. For example, what happens if the user input 60 (which can be a "future" value, 2060, as well as an old value, 1960)?

That being said, you could probably achieve what you want by modifying the input format of a `DatePicker` via the `inputFormat` prop I believe. You'll have to tests things out though since [the docs](https://mui.com/api/date-picker/) regarding this prop are not very ... extensive.

For the solution 1, there are validators within DatePicker, for example all the years before 1900 aren't valid. I believe you can also change the validators to fit your needs.

---

EDIT: I've set up a minimal environment to fiddle around with your code and came up with a (somewhat half-cooked) solution.

As you can see in this [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-dust-30e0x), we can take advantage of the method `getYear` to tell us if the year is after 1900 or not. It returns the difference between the year 1900 and the input. So if we input 199 for example, it'll return `-1701`. On the contrary, if we input say, 2021, it'll return `121`. That makes our first validation.

We also need to handle other cases by providing to `DatePicker` our own `onError` function.

**Be aware** that for dates with year > 1900 and <= 1911, the Greenwich Mean Time seems broken. (+9)

Finally, if we **really** want a 2-digit formatted date and **ONLY** for display purposes (or storing a string-typed date), we can take advantage of the function `format` from `date-fns`.

Comment: Thank you. But even if I got with solution 1, right now the validators don't work as I show in the example. So the user can go for two digit, the developer expects 4 digit and the result is a wrong value (see example in the post: input 20 results in the year 0020; even three digits: 202 results in year 0202). So the point is not primary the decission two or four digits, but going with 4 digits from developer perspective, should avoid two digit inputs - but in default this is possible.

Comment: Also I want to mention, that in my specific case it is a special app, which primary usage depends on this date input and other desktop apps in that company are using two digits, so all users are using two digit year input without thinking that much about it

Comment: I've edited my answer with a CodeSandbox link, please read the edited part and look at the code to see if it somewhat helps you.